# Не работает кнопка , в меню python/pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Всем привет! Очень нуждаюсь в помощи!
Хотел сделать меню для игры . Сначала сделал класс для кнопки button, потом функцию drawMenu которая должна отрисовывать меню пока что с 1 кнопкой - начать игру. Весь игровой цикл я поместил в отдельную функцию , которая должна выполнятся по щелчку мыши , но ничего не работает. 
P.S До этого пробовал делать кнопки похожим образом и все работало

мой класс button:

```
class button:
def __init__(self, width, height):
    self.width = width
    self.height = height


def draw(self, x, y, message, action):
    global mouse, click
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if  x < mouse[0] < x + self.width:
        if y < mouse[0]  < y + self.height:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (150, 150, 40), (x, y, self.width, self.height))
            if pygame.click[0] == 1:
                action()

        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (100, 100, 150), (x, y, self.width, self.height))

    else:        
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (100, 100, 150), (x, y, self.width, self.height))

    print_text(message, x + 3, y-3, )
```

моя функция drawMenu:

```
def drawMenu():
    global run,  clock
    startGame = button(120 , 60)
    show = True
    while show:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 800, 500))
        startGame.draw(340, 230, "Начать игру", game_started())
        pygame.display.update()   
        clock.tick(60)
```

P.P.S я начинающий программист так что ошибка может быть абсолютно тупая

Answer (score 1):

Все работает

```py
class button():
    def __init__(self, surf, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.surf = surf #Поверхность для отрисовки
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.counter = 0 #Счетчик нажатий кнопки. Зависит от clock.tick()

    def draw(self):
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        if  self.x < mouse[0] < self.x + self.width and self.y < mouse[1] < self.y + self.height:
            pygame.draw.rect(self.surf, (150, 150, 40), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
            if click[0] == 1:
                self.counter += 1
                print('clicked!!!', self.counter)
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(self.surf, (100, 100, 150), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

        else:        
            pygame.draw.rect(self.surf, (100, 200, 100), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))


def drawMenu():

    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption('game')
    sc = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    startGame = button(sc, 10, 10, 120 , 60)

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        startGame.draw()

        clock.tick(20)
        pygame.display.update()   

drawMenu()
```

Comment: Спасибо,  этот ответ завершает мои поиски меню для PyGame.  Есть специальная разработка для меню by @ppizarror, но она очень тяжеловесная(трудна в применении для "новиков"). Варианты с доп. использованием tkinter или wxWize в PyGame для тех кому нужны потоки и множественные окна.